# Could this function be sped up using some Numpy trick?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, optimization, neural-network, feed-forward

I have a personal implementation of a feed-forward neural network. If you are familiar with them then you know about the forward pass. It is inherently iterative, i. e., the results of the last computation (previous layer's output) is used in the next one. I have this function for forward feeding, i. e., the forward pass of an examples vector.

```py
    def forward_pass(self, example, keep_track=True):
        curr_layer = example.flatten()
        outputs = np.empty(self.L() - 1, dtype=np.ndarray)  # z^(l)
        activations = np.empty(self.L(), dtype=np.ndarray)  # a^(l)
        activations[0] = curr_layer
        for W, b, l in zip(self.W(), self.b(), range(self.L() - 1)):
            outputs[l] = (W @ curr_layer) + b
            if self.is_reg and (l == self.L() - 2):  # last layer regression
                activations[l + 1] = outputs[l]
                continue  # we should be done
            activations[l + 1] = self.act(outputs[l])
            curr_layer = activations[l + 1]
        return (outputs, activations) if keep_track else activations[-1]
```

As we can see, there is a loop involved. I can't imagine there being a way to get rid of it and do this in a more *vectorised* way but I have been surprised in past as to what can be accomplished with Numpy.

Do you see a way to speed up this function?

Comment: I cannot test the speed up, but are you are aware of the "magical" spped-up you can achieve with a numba decorator, like `@numba.njit`? This made it for me, in a similar case wheer I could not get vectorise a loop.

Comment: In general, you cannot do all the computation 'at once', in a fully vectorized way, because the layers are often different sizes. If the network is not too gigantic, many implementations just march through the layers consecutively, without even using a loop. You could potentially make this neater by making a Layer class, but if it's speed you want, I suspect you need the same strategy as Tensorflow and PyTorch: CUDA.

Comment: @GiovanniTardini could you perhaps provide an example with a generic function doing something in a loop vs the same function with the mentioned decorator?

Comment: Sure, look at the solution I got to my own question here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646410/numpy-sum-of-2d-array-along-axis-1-floating-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646410/numpy-sum-of-2d-array-along-axis-1-floating-range)